# Open GApps are not available for android 8.0

Tags: android, genymotion

i am trying to install google apps on genymotion. For that i clicked  [image] on right bar of emulator. but what i got is

[image]

i know there is second way of downloading separate google apps .zip file and drag into genymotion. **but what i want is within genymotion solution**

Answer (score 1):

You can install GApps from official [OpenGapps](http://opengapps.org/). There are different variants you can choose from, from small packages with only the most important apps, to big ones with all possible Google apps.

I suggest you to select **Nano** for a minimal installation. Also for emulators select as in this pic:[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked I just needed to download x86 version not x86_x64. If installation goes wrong just check the logcat.

Comment: No ups for an answer that helped?